# MDNS not advertising the network interface after network restart in systemd

Tags: embedded-linux, systemd, mdns, ifconfig, avahi

In systemd, MDNS (avahi-daemon) stops broadcasting the network interface after the network restart. However, for the same scenario, in system init, MDNS will work perfectly normal.

Tried:

1. Changed the avahi-daemon configuration file
2. restart the avahi-daemon after restarting the network
3. Checked the firewall (no firewall)
4. Tried systemd-resolved
5. Changed hostapd configuration

Answer (score 0):

I am so glad that I have it figured out. The reason why the MDNS stopped broadcasting is because the interface didn't properly restart.

In systemd, after the network restarts, it requires a reload of the configuration manually to generate an IP address. So after restarting the network, manually reloading the network interface configuration by `ifconfig interface down` and `ifconfig interface up` (`interface` need to be replaced by the real interface name).

Also, purely doing a `ifconfig interface up` won't work. The network interface probably has a cache. So bring the interface down `ifconfig down` can help remove the cache.

Please correct me if any of the description above is wrong. Thanks.